# Unable to reset security questions of Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

I have forgotten the **answers** to the security questions of my Apple ID. When attempting to log in, I am asked the **answer** two out of the three security questions. So, I tried to change them. But, now, I am asked to **answer** at least one of the security questions. So far, that is the only option I am getting to reset the **security questions and answers**. Contacting Support did not help in any way.

Is there any way to get my Apple ID back?

Comment: Knowing the answer to those questions is how you get security on your account. Just think if anyone could call Apple to have the questions reset - they could get access to your account...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, and I forgot it. So, they could either send me a code onto my email, or ask me the last 4 digits of my credit card (the one I used to buy Apple Music for two years now)

Comment: And people don't get credit cards scammed?

Comment: @SolarMike Not the one I used? I could show them the confirmation mail, my Govt. id proof, credit card statement, bank statement and so on !! There are trillion ways to prove my ownership. After all, since their data was breached once, they cant guarantee that the security questions were not changed without my permission!!

Comment: But you are the one who can't remember your own answers, perhaps try writing them down in future.